# Jupyter Notebook: Float div within cell

Tags: css, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

**Updated Wording**

I have a Jupyter notebook which is displaying a mesh of `ipywidgets`. I would like the "control panel" on the left hand side to be floating so it is always visible. I have tried setting the widget as `position: absolute` with the parent as `position: relative` but it does not change anything.

Below is an example of what I am showing.

[image: Notebook]

```py
import ipywidgets
import urllib.request

# Download a sample image
imgURL = "http://site.meishij.net/r/58/25/3568808/a3568808_142682562777944.jpg"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(imgURL, "example_image.jpg")

# Create 8 widgets with the same image
file = open("example_image.jpg", "rb")
image = file.read()

view1 = ipywidgets.Image(value=image, format='jpeg')
view2 = ipywidgets.Image(value=image, format='jpeg')
view3 = ipywidgets.Image(value=image, format='jpeg')
view4 = ipywidgets.Image(value=image, format='jpeg')
view5 = ipywidgets.Image(value=image, format='jpeg')
view6 = ipywidgets.Image(value=image, format='jpeg')
view7 = ipywidgets.Image(value=image, format='jpeg')
view8 = ipywidgets.Image(value=image, format='jpeg')

# Group them together
viewBox1 = ipywidgets.HBox(children=[view1, view2])
viewBox2 = ipywidgets.HBox(children=[view3, view4])
viewBox3 = ipywidgets.HBox(children=[view5, view6])
viewBox4 = ipywidgets.HBox(children=[view7, view8])
renderPane = ipywidgets.VBox(children=[viewBox1, viewBox2, viewBox3, viewBox4]) 

# Create a control panel
dropdown1 = ipywidgets.Dropdown(options=['opt1', 'opt2'], value='opt1', 
                                description='Choose an opt:', 
                                disabled=False)
dropdown2 = ipywidgets.Dropdown(options=['opt3', 'opt4'], value='opt3', 
                                description='Choose an opt:', 
                                disabled=False)

controlPane = ipywidgets.VBox([dropdown1, dropdown2])

# Update the layout (CSS)
renderPane.layout  = ipywidgets.Layout(flex='8 1 0%', width='auto') 
controlPane.layout = ipywidgets.Layout(flex='2 1 0%', width='auto', position='absolute', top='1em', right='1em')

# Put in the one widget
widget=ipywidgets.HBox([renderPane, controlPane], 
                        layout=ipywidgets.Layout(align_items='stretch', width='100%', position='relative'))

display(widget)
```

**Original Wording**

Within my Jupyter notebook I have a cell which is showing some widgets (`ipwidgets`). Within the left hand side there are a number of images etc, and on the right I have a 'control panel' used to change parameters.

I would like for this control panel (`ipywidgets.VBox`) to float so that if I scroll down inside the cell the panel is always visible.

I have tried to use `css` like

```
#float-vbox {
    position: fixed;
    top: 1em;
    right: 1em;
}
```

within the code `self.controls.layout   = ipywidgets.Layout(flex='2 1 0%', width='auto', position='fixed', top='1em', right='1em')`.

However this floats it on the whole page. Is there a way to float within the cell only?

Comment: An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the viewport. Give it a position: absolute and the parent element a position: relative;

Comment: Thanks @Jawad, I tried that but no luck.

The control panel:
`self.renderPane.layout = ipywidgets.Layout(flex='8 1 0%', width='auto')
self.controls.layout   = ipywidgets.Layout(flex='2 1 0%', width='auto', position='absolute', top='1em', right='1em')`

The Parent div:
`self.widget=ipywidgets.HBox([self.renderPane, self.controls], layout=ipywidgets.Layout(align_items='stretch', width='100%', position='relative'))`

Comment: show the html code